# Insert(bindValue) in the database

Tags: php

Why is this query inserted in the database twice?

```
$sql =$connect->prepare( 
"INSERT INTO `tbl_users`(`name`, `family`, `username`, `password`, `level`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

 $sql->execute(array($name,$family,$username,$password,$level));
```

Comment: something `$stmt->bind_param("sss", $val1, $val2, $val3 .... );` then `$sql->execute()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Comment: @devpro I think it's PDO, not MySQLi

Comment: The code you have shown would not do two inserts. You will need to show more of your code to debug this.

Comment: @Nick: i didnt see PDO tag here.

Comment: @devpro `bindValue` in the title, and the passing of an array of values to `execute`; both of those are PDO specific which is what made me think that.

Comment: @Nick & @ devpro : When running, two rows are inserted in the database.
What is your solution

Comment: There is no solution with the code you have posted.